# Jenkins agent- Connection not possible

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

I would like to connected via JNLP to the Jenkins controller server and getting always following error

```
Failing to obtain https://<controller-server>/buildserver/computer/CaptainBrowser/slave-agent.jnlp?encrypt=true
 java.io.IOException: https://<controller-server>/buildserver/computer/CaptainBrowser/slave-agent.jnlp?encrypt=true doesn't look like a JNLP file; content type was text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
at hudson.remoting.Launcher.parseJnlpArguments(Launcher.java:306)
at hudson.remoting.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:219)
at hudson.remoting.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:192)
```

Comment: what happens if you hit `https://<master-server>/buildserver/computer/CaptainBrowser/slave-agent.jnlp?encrypt=true` ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. For me the issue was that the Jenkins URL in 'Configure System' was set to 'http://...' instead of 'https://...'. This meant that when I set up a node, it showed the java command to run to be also use http. E.g it said
java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http:///computer//slave-agent.jnlp -secret 
Running it yielded 
'Failing to obtain http:///computer//slave-agent.jnlp?encrypt=true'
Changing the server URL to 'https' enabled it to work for me. It changed the command for a Jenkins node to be a 'https' URL and running that worked.

Answer (score 1):

Goto jenkins --> Manage jenkins --> configure system --> http://yoursystem ip:8080/ Make sue it will be http not https. Manage Jenkins --> Global security--> Agent -->
TCP port select fixed 50000 and Inbound TCP Agent Protocol/4 (TLS encryption) under agent protocol

[image: Screenshot of the above]

Create Agent node gain it will work

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it started working after adding HTTPS protocol to my security group for EC2 machines. Then again run jnlp command on to jenkins slave terminal and it will be connected.